# Want to know 1 formula in Excel

Tags: performance

How to get total answer as 41:00 with excel formula of 2 cells consist

20:00 & 21:00

I have tried Sum formula but getting 17:00 as answer

Comment: Consider giving examples of what you are trying to achieve and have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

To get total hours in number and not the hour of the day, use custom format [h] to the cell in question.

Right click the cell in which the result is expected--> Format Cells --> Custom and create or select [h]:mm:ss as format. If you do not want seconds, use or create [h]:mm format.

[image]